# Error with Entityset Mapping - EF5 - Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

My application was first started developing with EF3.5 and upgraded the Model/EDMX to EF5. I am trying to use a stored procedure which returns 2 resultsets. Both these results are a result of query and doesn't have any table with exact column order.

I have followed second part of the [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) and it compiles. However at run time it throws an error

> error 3027: No mapping specified for the following
>   EntitySet/AssociationSet - NotViewedReports, ViewedReports

**How can make this work? Any help is greatly appreciated**

Here is the entire Mapping for this Stored Proc

```
<EntityType Name="NotViewedReport">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="RecordID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="RecordID" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportId" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportDesc" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportLink" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="DistributionDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="ReportTypeId" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="IsLocked" Type="Boolean" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="EffectiveStartDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="EffectiveEndDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="Investor_ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="Investor_Name" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="ViewedReport">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="RecordID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="RecordID" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportId" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportDesc" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportLink" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="240" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="ReportDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="DistributionDate" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="Mr_Ms" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="Last_Name" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="First_MI" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="Company" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="LoginTime" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="Contact_ID" Type="Int32" Nullable="true" />
          <Property Name="LastViewed" Type="DateTime" Nullable="true" Precision="3" />
          <Property Name="Investor_Name" Type="String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="100" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
        </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>

......
<FunctionImport Name="GetBatchViewStatus">
            <Parameter Name="batchFrom" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <Parameter Name="batchTo" Mode="In" Type="Int32" />
            <ReturnType EntitySet="NotViewedReports" Type="Collection(IRISModel.NotViewedReport)" />
            <ReturnType EntitySet="ViewedReports" Type="Collection(IRISModel.ViewedReport)" />
          </FunctionImport>
        </EntityContainer>

.....
<FunctionImportMapping FunctionImportName="GetBatchViewStatus" FunctionName="IRISModel.Store.GetBatchViewStatus" >
              <ResultMapping>
                <EntityTypeMapping TypeName ="IRISModel.NotViewedReport">
                  <ScalarProperty Name="RecordID" ColumnName="RecordID" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportId" ColumnName="ReportId" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportDesc" ColumnName="ReportDesc" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportLink" ColumnName="ReportLink" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportDate" ColumnName="ReportDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="DistributionDate" ColumnName="DistributionDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportTypeId" ColumnName="ReportTypeId" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="IsLocked" ColumnName="IsLocked" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="EffectiveStartDate" ColumnName="EffectiveStartDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="EffectiveEndDate" ColumnName="EffectiveEndDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Investor_ID" ColumnName="Investor ID" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Investor_Name" ColumnName="Investor Name" />
                </EntityTypeMapping>
              </ResultMapping>
              <ResultMapping>
                <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IRISModel.ViewedReport">
                  <ScalarProperty Name="RecordID" ColumnName="RecordID" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportId" ColumnName="ReportId" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportDesc" ColumnName="ReportDesc" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportLink" ColumnName="ReportLink" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="ReportDate" ColumnName="ReportDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="DistributionDate" ColumnName="DistributionDate" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Mr_Ms" ColumnName="Mr/Ms" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Last_Name" ColumnName="Last Name" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="First_MI" ColumnName="[First/MI]" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Company" ColumnName="Company" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="LoginTime" ColumnName="LoginTime" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Contact_ID" ColumnName="Contact ID" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="LastViewed" ColumnName="LastViewed" />
                  <ScalarProperty Name="Investor_Name" ColumnName="Investor Name" />
                </EntityTypeMapping>
            </ResultMapping>
          </FunctionImportMapping>            
          </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
```

Comment: Since the objects you are returning are not entities and you don't need to track them can you try changing them to ComplexTypes and in the ReturnType element remove the EntitySet attribute? ComplexTypes don't have EntitySets so the error you have should be gone.